# How to fix this Eslint Use the spread operator instead of '.apply()'

Tags: arrays, reactjs, apply, eslint

I learn react and dont understand how to fix this. From this [source](https://github.com/plangrid/react-file-viewer/blob/78f15818295f0c55c549614083ce655cd2a67079/src/components/drivers/pdf-viewer.jsx)
I look in the [Rule Details](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-spread) for this rule:

> Use the spread operator instead of '.apply()'.

But have tried but it's never working to reformate this code to comply with this rule:

```
renderPages() {
    const { pdf, containerWidth, zoom } = this.state;
    const { disableVisibilityCheck } = this.props;
    if (!pdf) return null;
    const pages = Array.apply(null, { length: pdf.numPages });
    return pages.map((v, i) => (
        <PDFPage
            index={i + 1}
            key={`pdfPage_${uniqueId()}`}
            pdf={pdf}
            containerWidth={containerWidth}
            zoom={zoom * INCREASE_PERCENTAGE}
            disableVisibilityCheck={disableVisibilityCheck}
        />
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TasosBu good to know. I debug and see that `const pages` get the number 1 because the pdf have one page

Comment: I was wrong @Tord Larsen! It inherites it from the function prototype!
You should construct a new Array with `const pages  = new Array(pdf.numPages)`

Comment: The second parameter of `Array.apply` should be an array. Why are you giving an object?

Comment: This is the [file](https://github.com/plangrid/react-file-viewer/blob/78f15818295f0c55c549614083ce655cd2a67079/src/components/drivers/pdf-viewer.jsx) that this code is in

Answer (score 5):

The message suggest using this kind of expression:

```
const pages = { ...{ length: pdf.numPages }};
```

For instance, the following code compiles:

```
const somePdf = {
  numPages: 10,
  pageSize: 'A4',
}

const pages = { ...{ length: somePdf.numPages }};

console.log(JSON.stringify(pages))

// returns "{ length: 10}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that rule is not that important, so if you want you can simply disable the rule by adding this line to your rules in the `eslintrc.js` file:

```
'rules': {
  ...
  'prefer-spread': ['off']
}
```